# Characters are not bold if there is a Greek character or enhanced text

Tags: gnuplot

If a terminal font is set to bold and there are Greek characters in axis title, legend or label, or there are subscripts and superscripts, then the non-Greek characters are displayed with regular density. Is it a bug, or there is a way to display these characters bold? Gnuplot version is 4.6.7.

```
set term pngcairo enhanced font 'Arial Bold,20'
set output 'test.png'
set xlabel '{/Symbol g}123abc'
set ylabel '123_4abc'
set label '{/Symbol b}abc' at graph 0.5, graph 0.7
set label 'abc' at graph 0.5, graph 0.4
plot 1 t '{/Symbol g}123', 2 t '123456789'
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is a bug, which is fixed in gnuplot 5. My output with version 5.0.5:

[image]

Here, you see, that now only the greek glyphs are drawn with normal weight, all others are bold. The reason for that is, that you use `Arial Bold` as font, but with `/Symbol` you change the font to Symbol with normal weight.

Simply use bold symbol font, with `set xlabel '{/Symbol:Bold g}123abd'` (gnuplot 5 syntax):

[image]

Comment: Is there a workaround for gnuplot 4? All my scripts are written for this version.